# Converting List To Maps in Java 8

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, guava, multimap, collectors

I am loading a log file as input stream and need to do aggregate processing on the matching values on each line, also I need to store duplicates while saving the lines in MultiMap, I am finding trouble collecting the below stream stored into List as `Multimap<String, List<String>>`

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(inFileName))) {
    List<String> matchedValues = stream
                    .flatMap(s -> MultiPatternSpliterator.matches(s, p1))
                    .map(r -> r.group(1))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    matchedValues.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

How to convert the same to store the values in Map with duplicate values.

Comment: Do you want group 1 as the key and all the groups as the value?

Comment: yes, the pattern matches and get the values from log line as <reTimeStamp, reHostName, reServiceTime>, i need to store Map<<reTimeStamp>, <reTimeStamp, reHostName, reServiceTime>) - TimeStamp is the Key as well it is the value in the List<String>.

Comment: Don't you want either a `Multimap<String, String>` OR a `List<String, List<String>>`? I can't see why you need multiple List<String> per key.

Comment: In my Map i need to store 3 values and 1 of the values is also a Key, more info on my above comment.

Comment: Would a Map<String, List<List<String>>> work too, then you could just use standard Java (with the outer list providing for multiple events at the same timestamp)

Comment: @Shan - I think you will get better answers if you give more detail on what your `matches` does and what your goal is. Please try to post a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what you really want, but given that you say you need *"log line as `<reTimeStamp, reHostName, reServiceTime>`"* to be stored as *"`Map<<reTimeStamp>, <reTimeStamp, reHostName, reServiceTime>`"* I'd go with:

```
        Map<String, List<String>> matchedValues = stream
                .flatMap(MultiPatternSpliterator::matches)
                .map(r -> Arrays.asList(r.group(1), r.group(2), r.group(3)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        groups -> groups.get(0),
                        Function.identity()));
```

*If* key (i.e. timestamp) can be duplicated, use `(List)Multimap` which would give you a list of lists per key:

```
        ListMultimap<String, List<String>> matchedValues = stream
                .flatMap(MultiPatternSpliterator::matches)
                .map(r -> Arrays.asList(r.group(1), r.group(2), r.group(3)))
                .collect(toImmutableListMultimap(
                        groups -> groups.get(0),
                        Function.identity()));
```

I would be easier if you showed some example input and output.